# Show field label when using tokens in "Global Custom Text" field in Views?

Tags: views, entities, tokens

How can I show the field label when using tokens in Global field in Views.

To reproduce:

In a view:

1) Add field: **title-field** and enable to "Create a label" with value "My title".

2) Add field: **Global Custom Text**. In this field I use the token **[title_field]** for the text.

In the result the label is not shown. The token just print out the value but not the label. Even when I checked  "Create a label" with value "My title" for the **title-field**

Can I get this? I know that this can be done with the [views_php](https://drupal.org/project/views_php) module but, I don't want to enable this module just to workaround this.

Comment: Why can't you hard code.. ? Any way it doesn't change contextually right ? Am i missing something here ! ?

Comment: with views_php I can use t() to create  translatable labels. But I've read that this module adversely affects the performance of the site.

Comment: So you would like to display translated text of a label .. Makes sense.. Can you update your question ?

Comment: have you found a solution? because I also stuck on this problem
[enter link description here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198877/label-views-ignored-in-rewriting)

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to just create your own label by typing it in.

ex 1: `Title: [title_field]`

ex 2: `<b>Title:</b> <br>[title_field]`

Comment: This wouldn't work to translate labels if you have multilingual site.

Comment: @usmanjutt84 indeed, if you're concerned about that, you would use a template file and put the label inside the t() function.